# unable to use interceptor binding interface with @Target({METHOD, TYPE}) for post construct methods?

Tags: ejb, interceptor, java-ee-7, glassfish-4.1

I am trying to define a logger interceptor with an interceptor binding interface :

```
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
public @interface OperationLogger {

    @Nonbinding
    public String operationName() default "";
    @Nonbinding
    public String details() default "";
}
```

but glassfish 4.1 returns this error message in compile :

> An interceptor for lifecycle callbacks Interceptor [class
>   com.adldoost.dwm.security.interceptor.OperationLoggerInterceptor
>   intercepts @OperationLogger] declares and interceptor binding
>   interface com.adldoost.dwm.security.interceptorbinding.OperationLogger
>   with METHOD as its @Target.

also Netbeans 8.1 editor tells :

> An interceptor for lifecycle callbacks may only declare interceptor
>   binding types that are defined as @Target(TYPE). Interceptor
>   com.adldoost.dwm.security.interceptor.OperationLoggerInterceptor
>   declares mismatch interceptor binding
>   com.adldoost.dwm.security.interceptorbinding.OperationLogger.

So what is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to intercept a lifecycle callback method like this:

```
@Stateless
public class MrBean {

    @PostConstruct
    @OperationLogger
    private void init() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Or just

```
@Stateless
@OperationLogger
public class MrBean {
    @PostConstruct
    // ...
}
```

You can't intercept lifecycle callbacks (including `@PreDestroy`) using an interceptor binding with `METHOD` as it's target. Make `OperationLogger`'s target just `@Target(TYPE)`, or don't annotate lifecycle callbacks, which includes annotating the entire class.

Comment: my target is set to : @Target({METHOD, TYPE}) not only method ! do i need to change it to only TYPE ?!

Comment: As I said, either annotate your binding with just `@Target(TYPE)` or do not add `@OperationLogger` to your class and it's lifecycle callback methods.